# Count duplicate cells in a column based on another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, pivot-table, countif

Sample data:

```
Event    Client
 400      1
 400      1
 401      1
 402      2
 402      2
 402      2
 400      3
 401      3
 402      3
 403      3
```

This table represents one ticket to an event per row. I am trying to determine how many events a client attended (but I don't care how many tickets they bought to an event). The result I am trying to get:

```
Client 1: 2 events
Client 2: 1 event
Client 3: 4 events
```

I could write a Python script to determine this information, but I feel like there might exist an Excel function I can use to achieve the same result.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight your entire dataset and press "alt" then "a" then "m". That will remove duplicate entries, then a countif(B:B, B1) will count the number of entries for that specific client number.

`Countif(B:B,1)` will work for client 1
`Countif(B:B,2)` will work for client 2

But if you reference the cells they will be in (B1 and below) then drag down your formula it will work automatically.

Comment: Excellent, and a great illustration of the dangers of overthinking. I removed duplicates based on the 2 values I was looking at then did the countif followed by a copy/paste values and deduping to get a clean list. Thank you for saving me from writing a script I didn't need to write!

Answer (score 1):

May be easiest with Excel 2013 but still easy in Excel 2007 with a PivotTable:

[image: SO28993685 example]

and a helper column with formula:

```
=COUNT(E3:H3)
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is interested in automatically updated solution, just list the unique client ids in a table (e.g. with `=ROW()-1` formula) and compute the number of unique events with following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
  N(EC[Client] = [@Client]),
  1 / COUNTIFS(EC[Event], EC[Event], EC[Client], EC[Client]))
```

where:

- `EC` is the name of your Event_Client table and `[@Client]` is a cell in the current row of your Unique_Clients table
- `N` is an Excel function to convert boolean values to 0/1
- `1/COUNTIFS(col1,col1, col2,col2)` is a trick to [count unique rows](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/count-unique-values.html) - it will produce an array
- `SUMPRODUCT` is used to avoid having to use an array formula